# Get lines between 2 specific lines in Lua

Tags: io, lua

Using `io.open` to read a file, now I trying to get specific lines between 2 other lines.

The file content is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<somethings>
    <something attribute="some" />
    <something attribute="some1" />
</somethings>
```

And I want to get lines between `<somethings>` and `</somethings>` stored in a table. What I have so far:

```
local file = io.open(file, "r")
local arr = {}

for line in file:lines() do
    table.insert(arr, line);
end
```

But it inserts all the lines into array.

Comment: Before I write an answer (there's already an accepted one), have you tried gmatch?

Comment: Well ```for text in string.gmatch(file_contents, "<somethings>(.*)</somethings>") print(text) end``` appears to work, I don't have enough knowledge on string patterns to guarantee satisfaction though.

Comment: Is that all your file is? If the file format is perfectly static the accepted answer may be acceptable, but in general you should use an actual XML parser to... well, parse xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
local collecting=false    
for line in file:lines() do
    if line:match("</somethings>") then
       collecting=false  -- or break if there is only one block
    end
    if collecting then
       table.insert(arr, line)
    end
    if line:match("<somethings>") then
       collecting=true
    end
end
```

Comment: Tried it, just prints nothing at all.

Comment: @KrisInception Correct. It just collects the lines into the table. If you want to print them then print the lines from the table. Your original code didn't print anything either.

Comment: Yeah so dumb of me, forgot to actually return the table from my function. Yeah this worked like a charm, thanks a lot. Accepting this as fast as I can :)